# Simple automation tool for logging into website and updating

Tags: web-scraping, automation

There are a couple websites I routine log into to update calendar information. This is very routine without a lot of change. With the exception of the log in fields, it only involves right click (no other keyboard input). What "language" would be well suited for the task? I think website scraping would be overkill and am considering Autohotkey or AutoIt. It probably would be best if I could record the script by doing it manually first, then tweak the script by hand.

My default browser is Firefox but for this task I don't care what is used. Speed and performance is not a huge deal, as the task is fairly simple.

Comment: selenium+Firefox >>> browser automation

Answer (score 4):

As you were talking about web scraping, I would assume you have bit of coding background.

Just as mentioned in comment, You are searching for **[Selenium WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/)**. It's a advanced library for automating browser activities (for IE,FF & Chrome).

There are 2 options available with Selenium

1. [**Selenium IDE**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/): This is Firefox plugin, helps in record and play. Auto generates code, however it's of old version.
2. ***Writing selenium WebDriver scripts***. It has learning curve which is relatively easy but not as easy as Autohotkey or AutoIt.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Since the website needs a password to log in, would this be stored locally or in the cloud with Selenium IDE? I'd prefer not to have my log in credentials stored in some random cloud.

Comment: AFAIK it doesn't save anything (explicitly cloud). After recording browser activities user needs to save the script on local machine else it will clear everything when you close/restart the plugin.

Comment: It turns out Selenium IDE is insufficient. How do you get started with WebDriver? I tried searching and everything seems very complicated and not worth it (e.g. need to set up Hudson, Glassfish, Maven etc). I would like to use Netbeans with Java.

Comment: @Celeritas: No need for maven and all other stuff, directly download webdriver jar http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.0/selenium-java-3.0.1.zip) and start using it. Follow this url  (http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example) for getting started with webdriver as it shows basic scirpting with webdriver.

Answer (score 2):

Both AutoHotkey or AutoIt have IE automating capabilities and can also be used to control the selenium WebDriver

An automatic IE login tutorial using build-in Autohotkey functions can be found here [How-to: Create a shortcut that automatically logs in to any website](https://jszapp.com/how-to-create-a-shortcut-that-automatically-logs-in-to-any-website/)